# bypassing javascript to get page source

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

1)I am building an app for downloading all my pictures from my instagram profile.

2)I don't want to use instagram api so i searched and i find Selenium Webdriver and i add this package to my project

3)I am using c# to build android app (Xamarin)  check below Code.

```
    string url = "https://www.instagram.com/" + _theUsername;
    IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.Url = url;
    string source = driver.PageSource;
```

4)By Using above code i am getting below error :-

```
 OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException: The geckodriver file does not exist in the current directory or in a directory on the PATH environment variable
```

5)Is it possible to use this in xamarin? i need to find a way to do this
any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: maybe the best way to do this using the webview to extract the page source

Comment: i did manage to load the page inside the webview with javascript on and everything works perfectly but as i said i need the page source and i don't want to show the page

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Selenium, but getting the page source for a url is easy with HttpClient:

```
string url = "https://www.instagram.com/" + _theUsername;
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient()){
    var response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
    Debug.WriteLine(response);
}
```

and `response` will have your page source. And if you do not want to show the web page then there is no need for a `WebView` anyway.

Comment: yes it is easy but what i want is bypassing the javascript because the html source is rendered with javascript and if i use HttpClient it returns just some useless tags

Comment: Ah, that does complicate things. Probably easiest to just use the instagram API.

Comment: i did make that work with exporting page source from webview now everthings works great but i have problem [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41996269/how-to-auto-click-on-a-link-in-webview?noredirect=1#comment71194271_41996269