# how to auto click on a link in webview

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

for getting all images from the website i exported the page source with web view and i did extract all of the img tag

but the website only show's 20 images and in the bottom of the website is a link for Load More

```
<a class="_8imhp _glz1g" href="/nasa/?max_id=1376001113798851033">Load more</a>
```

And this is my code for extracting the page source

```
            public override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
           {
            base.OnPageFinished(view, url);

            view.LoadUrl("javascript:window.HtmlViewer.showHTML('<head>' + document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML + '</head>');" +
                         "javascript:window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight); ");

           }
```

so i want to automatically click on that link and get all the images possible

i seen a sample with python uses Webdriver to do this

```
# Click on "Load more..." label
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//html/body/span/div/div/div/section/div/span/a/span[2]/span/span")
element.click()
```

so i can not use selenium webdriver and my only choice is to use webview

so far i make this work and only problem is that load more Link

so guys any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you extract the link target and re-load the page with the new URL? Assuming the page's URL was http://images.example.org/nasa/ which shows 20 images, and after clicking on "load more", the URL was http://images.example.org/nasa/?max_id=123456, then on the first load only obtain the link, and reload the page with that link.

Comment: no i can't because url is random and i use webview in invisible viewstate to just extract the page source and display images in recyclerview

Comment: i found a way to click that link this the code `view.LoadUrl(@"javascript:window.HtmlViewer.showHTML('<head>' + document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML + '</head>');" +
                              @"javascript:(function(){document.getElementsByClassName('_8imhp').click();})" +
                              @"javascript:window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);");` but i get this error `[INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier", source:  (1)`